# Spring Boot - Programmatically load properties files, including YAML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

I'm trying to programmatically read Spring-style properties files, including YAML-formatted files.

What I have somewhat works, but it ends up flattening the YAML and so I end up with keys that are all mixed up and when I try to map it to a specific object, it gets confused.

Here is what I have (in Kotlin):

```
import my.project.Properties
import java.util.Properties as JavaProperties

fun loadConfig(configFiles: List<String>): Properties =
  JavaProperties().apply {
    putAll(appProperties.defaultConfig)
    (if (configFiles.isEmpty()) appProperties.defaultConfigFiles else configFiles)
      .forEach { PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(this, FileSystemResource(it)) }
  }.let {
    // throws exception because it was flattened
    objectMapper.convertValue(it, Properties::class.java)
  }
```

If I have a config file like this:

```
a:
  b:
    c: 1
```

I would want it to end up something equivalent to this in the Java Properties:

```
mapOf("a" to mapOf("b" to mapOf("c" to 1)))
```

Instead, I just get something like this:

```
mapOf("c" to 1)
```

It totally flattens it out and throws away the hierarchy entirely.

I'd prefer not to just use a YAML parser and do it myself, because I would like to allow the "normal" Spring style property files as well.

Note: These have to be loaded at run-time because the application is actually for running against something else, so I can't just let Spring handle it automatically like a normally would.

Comment: Your approach won't work, since you're using wrong tool for the job. `fillProperties` discard idents, and YAML is all about idents. Parse YAML files line by line and keep track of idents by yourself, if you don't want to use a library for that.

Comment: Spring is able to parse YAML property files somehow and do everything properly. Is there any way to parse it like Spring does, just avoiding specifying the config file at startup.

Comment: Spring just uses SnakeYAML under the hood. I would suggest doing the same.